# Convert existing app to use Fragments

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, fragment

I am new to Android and have an app on the Market that I would like to convert to use Fragments so it could take advantage of the tablet in landscape mode and have both activities side by side.  All of the examples I can find out there use a listview with a image or text in the right column and uses the FragmentList class.  My app has an Activity that has buttons and depending on what buttons or spinners they select it then displays another activity.  Can anyone recommend a tutorial or article on how to do this?  I have read the Google blog but found it confusing and wasn't sure how to use it to modify my existing code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good tutorial http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/programmatic-and-layout-fragments/